# Is it possible to study a time-dependent Hamiltonian in Schrödinger picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Operators in Heisenberg picture are time-dependent while those in Schrödinger picture are time-independent, and they are related by $$A_H(t)=U^\dagger(t,t_0)A_S(t_0)U(t,t_0)$$ where $U(t,t_0)$ is the unitary evolution operator.

Does it mean it is not possible to work with the Schrödinger picture for time-dependent Hamiltonians? If yes, what does it even mean, in this case, to work in the Schrodinger picture because the operators are time-dependent?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/2451

Comment: The treatments I have seen start with a time-dependent wave equation and then just omit the parts that average to zero to form the more simple time-independent problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. You just pose the Schrödinger equation,
$$
i\hbar\partial_t |\psi(t)\rangle = \hat H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle,
$$
and you solve it. Or what do you mean by "how does that work?"?

Comment: But if the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ is dependent of $t$, is it anymore the Schrodinger picture? @EmilioPisanty

Comment: Well, time-dependent Hamiltonians within the context of the Schroedinger equation mean that there's an external interaction of the system which manifests itself by a time-dependent potential term

Comment: @DanielC How does your response answer my question about the Schrodinger picture?

Comment: @SRS Yes, of course it's still the Schrödinger picture. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Because operators in Schrodinger picture are time-independent. Right? @EmilioPisanty

Comment: @SRS You mix up the dependence on $t$ and $t_0$. The dependence on $t_0$ exists also in the time-independent case

Comment: @SRS No, that's an oversimplified view. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/310392/8563) is what a picture is: it tells you how operators/states evolve, but it never rules out explicit time dependence of operators. If it helps, choose *any* hamiltonian you like, and look at how the different pictures treat $\hat A =f(t) \mathbb I$.